# Cucumber not seeing steps in javascript project

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests, cucumber

I just cannot make it up why cucumber does not see the steps.

Here is my structure. Currently only test.feature matters, as i tried to simplify everything:

[image]

Here is my test.feature:

[image]

Here is my test.steps:

[image]

Here is my very much simplified now world.js:

[image]

As you can see the steps are not seen by the feature.

Here is the test result:
[image]

I tried manipulations with regexps, file names, folder moves, etc. Maybe somebody can give me a hint what else I can try.

EDITED: I added cucumber version used and cucumberOpts:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show your protractor conf file to see how configure `cucumbeOpts` and package.json to know which version of Cucumber  you used.

Comment: Hi, yong. I added the cucumberOpts and the cucumber version in package json. Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is for different Cucumber version, it has different pattern to write step defintion.

**You used Cucumber 4, but your step definition pattern is for Cucumber 1.**

For Cucumber 3 and 4, step definition should look like:

```
var {Given, Then, When} = require('cucumber');

When(/^i load the app$/, function(){
    ...
});
```

[More detail](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/HEAD/docs/support_files/step_definitions.md)

For Cucumber 2, step definition should look like:

```
var {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');

defineSupportCode(function ({ Given, When, Then }) {

    When(/^i load the app$/, function () {
        ...;
    });

}
```

[More detail](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/2.x/docs/support_files/step_definitions.md)

For Cucumber 1, step definition should look like:

```
module.exports = function() {

    this.When(/^i load the app$/, function() {
        ...;
    });

};
```

[More detail](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/1.x/docs/support_files/step_definitions.md)

FYI, `pretty` format removed in Cucumber 4, so you can't config it in `cucumberOpts`:

```
cucumberOpts: {
   format: ['pretty']
}
```

If you want the `pretty` back, please install another package: `cucumber-pretty`, and add it in `cucumberOptions`:

```
cucumberOpts: {
   format: ['node_modules/cucumber-pretty']
}
```

[More detail](https://github.com/yongcy/automation/tree/master/protractor/protractor-cucumber4-scaffold)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your folder structure is little off. Can you try something like below. I believe you need to have features and step_definitions folders in the same directory for cucumber to find step definitions. If not, you can provide `--require` parameter and tell cucumber explicitly where your step_definitions are like below

```
 cucumber.js test/features/paypalreg.feature --require test/features/step_definitions/ --format=pretty
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, nilesh. I will try this.

Comment: The folders were not the issue, though thanks for the require hint.